# Python urllib2 resume download doesn't work when network reconnects

Tags: python, urllib2, resume-download

I'm using urllib2 to make a resuming downloader, roughly based on [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/83208-resuming-download-of-a-file/) method. I can end the program and re-start it, and it starts downloading where it left off, downloading the file that ends up the same size as if it were downloaded all at once.

However, I have tested it when disabling and reenabling network, and it doesn't download correctly. The file size ends up longer than the file should be, and the file doesn't work correctly. Is there something I missed, or could this be a urllib2 bug?

```
    import urllib2
    opener = urllib2.build_opener();

    self.count = 0 # Counts downloaded size.
    self.downloading = True
    while (not(self.success) and self.downloading):
        try:
            self.Err = ""
            self._netfile = self.opener.open(self.url)
            self.filesize = float(self._netfile.info()['Content-Length'])

            if (os.path.exists(self.localfile) and os.path.isfile(self.localfile)):
                self.count = os.path.getsize(self.localfile)
            print self.count,"of",self.filesize,"downloaded."
            if self.count >= self.filesize:
                #already downloaded
                self.downloading = False
                self.success = True
                self._netfile.close()
                return

            if (os.path.exists(self.localfile) and os.path.isfile(self.localfile)):
                #File already exists, start where it left off:
                #This seems to corrupt the file sometimes?
                self._netfile.close()
                req = urllib2.Request(self.url)
                print "file downloading at byte: ",self.count
                req.add_header("Range","bytes=%s-" % (self.count))
                self._netfile = self.opener.open(req)
            if (self.downloading): #Don't do it if cancelled, downloading=false.
                next = self._netfile.read(1024)
                self._outfile = open(self.localfile,"ab") #to append binary
                self._outfile.write(next)
                self.readsize = desc(self.filesize) # get size mb/kb
                self.count += 1024
                while (len(next)>0 and self.downloading):
                    next = self._netfile.read(1024)
                    self._outfile.write(next)
                    self.count += len(next)
                self.success = True
        except IOError, e:
            print e
            self.Err=("Download error, retrying in a few seconds: "+str(e))
            try:
                self._netfile.close()
            except Exception:
                pass
            time.sleep(8) #Then repeat
```

Comment: There is already (almost) drop-in urllib replacement which can do resume: http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/

Comment: Have you tried it with disabling/enabling network? Does it automatically re-download correctly?

Comment: I think it was used by some of Linux package manages internally, so it should be pretty well tested - I have been succefully using it long time ago myself. It even has a setting for number of retries etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added self._outfile.close() with the self._netfile.close() in the IOError handler, that seems to have fixed it. I guess this error was caused by opening for appending again without closing it.

Comment: This probably had to do with _outfile.close() not getting a chance to flush the buffer.  A lot of file operations are buffered for speed and .close() would flush the content in memory to disk making the file the right length, and having the right content.