# Python equivalent of a given wget command

Tags: python, wget

I'm trying to create a Python function that does the same thing as this wget command:

```
wget -c --read-timeout=5 --tries=0 "$URL"
```

`-c` - Continue from where you left off if the download is interrupted.

`--read-timeout=5` - If there is no new data coming in for over 5 seconds, give up and try again.  Given `-c` this mean it will try again from where it left off.

`--tries=0` - Retry forever.

Those three arguments used in tandem results in a download that cannot fail.

**I want to duplicate those features in my Python script, but I don't know where to begin...**

Comment: Well, no, the download *can* fail for many reasons but yeah.  Have you looked into the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module?

Comment: @Iguananaut It should be noted that downloads can be interrupted with Ctrl+c on purpose, with the command-line wget tool, anyway (I believe this is the standard way to pause them in wget, using `wgetb -c the_URL` to resume). See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=991864

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html) should work. 
Just set it up in a while(not done) loop, check if a localfile already exists, if it does send a GET with a RANGE header, specifying how far you got in downloading the localfile. 
Be sure to use read() to append to the localfile until an error occurs.

This is also potentially a duplicate of [Python urllib2 resume download doesn't work when network reconnects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963283/python-urllib2-resume-download-doesnt-work-when-network-reconnects)

Comment: When I try `urllib.request.urlopen` or `urllib.request.Request` with a string containting the url as the url argument, I get `ValueError: unknown url type`

Comment: @XamuelDvorak Are you actually entering a URL? A url requires the type, e.g. `http://`, `ftp://`.

Comment: I was using 'stackoverflow.com', which, in my browser, has nothing of that sort in front of it.

Comment: It shows that for other websites though. I'll try your solution

Answer (score 158):

There is also a nice Python module named [`wget`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget) that is pretty easy to use. Keep in mind that the package has not been updated since 2015 and has not implemented a number of important features, so it may be better to use other methods. It depends entirely on your use case. For simple downloading, this module is the ticket. If you need to do more, there are other solutions out there.

```
>>> import wget
>>> url = 'http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3'
>>> filename = wget.download(url)
100% [................................................] 3841532 / 3841532>
>> filename
'razorback.mp3'
```

Enjoy.

However, if `wget` doesn't work (I've had trouble with certain PDF files), try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/1224827).

**Edit:** You can also use the `out` parameter to use a custom output directory instead of current working directory.

```
>>> output_directory = <directory_name>
>>> filename = wget.download(url, out=output_directory)
>>> filename
'razorback.mp3'
```

Comment: yes I have posted here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747913/facing-issue-with-wget-in-python?noredirect=1#comment78456827_45747913

Comment: Sorry for late reply, didn't see this notification for some reason. You need to `pip install wget` most likely.

Comment: @AshishKarpe If you're on Ubuntu, try sudo apt-get install python3-wget.

Comment: @Blairg32, The question is wanting to know how to continue a download (not how to start one, as shown in your answer). The Python wget documentation doesn't seem to say anything about continuing downloads. If you know something about it, please say (maybe it's automatic in the module).

Comment: @Shule That's a really good point that I hadn't even noticed until you brought it up. I haven't played with the continue parameter at all with this `wget` Python module, but here is the source if you want to check it out: https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-wget

Comment: `wget` comes with very few options and doesn't seem to be maintained. `requests` is superior in every way.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster This is the only use case I would argue with you. `wget` offers a very simple function: `wget`. It offers a nice interface that acts exactly like the Linux command and does that one thing very well. It probably doesn't require much maintenance since it's such a simple function. And if you're worried about it, can simply fork it :)

Comment: @Blairg23 Meanwhile the python wget package explicitly says, it's not options compatible with the original `wget` utility. FYI, you can't even set the User-Agent header, can you?

Comment: For anyone willing to use it as a replacement as wget with all the options it won't work. The only option supported by this is `out` and it's also abandoned. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51812486/8608146 is a better answer than this

Comment: Agree to disagree. The zen of Python would state `simple > complex` and this fits well in that. Just 3 lines of code and an import.

Comment: Sorry for the lazyness - probably is written somewhere - is the wget.download command blocking? i.e. - would >> for - wget.download - be downloading in parallel or should I do something extra for that?

Answer (score 32):

I had to do something like this on a version of linux that didn't have the right options compiled into wget. This example is for downloading the memory analysis tool 'guppy'. I'm not sure if it's important or not, but I kept the target file's name the same as the url target name...

Here's what I came up with:

```
python -c "import requests; r = requests.get('https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/guppy/guppy-0.1.10.tar.gz') ; open('guppy-0.1.10.tar.gz' , 'wb').write(r.content)"
```

That's the one-liner, here's it a little more readable:

```
import requests
fname = 'guppy-0.1.10.tar.gz'
url = 'https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/guppy/' + fname
r = requests.get(url)
open(fname , 'wb').write(r.content)
```

This worked for downloading a tarball. I was able to extract the package and download it after downloading.

EDIT:

To address a question, here is an implementation with a progress bar printed to STDOUT. There is probably a more portable way to do this without the `clint` package, but this was tested on my machine and works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from clint.textui import progress
import requests

fname = 'guppy-0.1.10.tar.gz'
url = 'https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/guppy/' + fname

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
    for chunk in progress.bar(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), expected_size=(total_length/1024) + 1): 
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
```

Comment: `python -m ensurepip && python -m pip install --upgrade pip && python -c "import os, sys, pip._vendor.requests; rq=pip._vendor.requests.get(sys.argv[1], stream=True); open(os.path.basename(sys.argv[1]), 'wb').write(rq.content)" http://httpbin.org/encoding/utf8 && diff -u ./utf8 <(curl -fSsl http://httpbin.org/encoding/utf8); cat ./utf8` 

# Python > ensurepip docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#command-line-interface 

# Pip docs > Vendoring policy: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/development/vendoring-policy/

Comment: Though does `os.basename` fail with forward-slash URL ~paths on windows?
`test "brotli" == "$(python -c "import sys, urllib.parse; print(urllib.parse.urlparse(sys.argv[1]).path.rsplit('/',1)[-1])" "https://httpbin.org/path/to/brotli#fragment")"`

Answer (score 28):

A solution that I often find simpler and more robust is to simply execute a terminal command within python. In your case:

```
import os
import shlex
url = 'https://www.someurl.com'
os.system(f"wget -c --read-timeout=5 --tries=0 {shlex.quote(url)}")
```

As always, be aware of unsanitized input potentially allowing injections. [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) is only suitable for Unix shells.

Comment: When I get a downvote, especially for providing a completely different approach, I like to know why. Care to explain ?

Comment: It looks like the args for os.system are improperly escaped. One " too many at the end.

Additionally, it doesn't work on windows because it has no wget. For that you need to go here: https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ download it and add it to the environment (PATH). Good solution though, upvoting ;)

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks :)

Comment: Use `subprocess`. **ALWAYS** use `subprocess`. Trivially easy to pown a machine that uses `os.system` like this for remote user input.

Comment: `subprocess` without `shell=True` (or something that wraps subprocess like sarge; which does quoting to prevent shell escape vulnerabilities)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні How would you pown a machine in this situation?

Comment: @gomennathan not in *this* case where the url happens to be hardcoded on the previous line; but if the `url` comes from user input as is all too common it just suffices to provide something like `https://www.google.com"; python3 -c "code for reverse shell"; echo "Powned`; the code for reverse shell can be something like this one: https://medium.com/@songchai.d01/how-to-create-a-reverse-shell-in-python-41fe75d88521

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні So, contrary to what you said, it is not trivially easy to pown a machine "that uses `os.system` like this".

Comment: For other readers: `os.system` is fine here, nobody is getting owned by this, although it's worth using `subprocess` because it has a lot of other improvements over `os.system`. If you were concerned about users injecting malicious code into `url`, the solution is to validate and sanitize `url` (maybe with `urlparse`) before plugging it into the command, not to rely on `subprocess` to clean up your dirty input after the fact.

Comment: @gomennathan so how do you suggest to validate the url with `urlparse`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні This is a completely separate matter from the Q&A post you are commenting on. You can ask a separate question on stackoverflow, "How do you validate a URL with `urlparse`?" and I'm sure you will get many great explanations, including from me if I see it.

Comment: @gomennathan Thank you for your suggestion. I have had great success with asking questions on Stack Overflow before, and have answered a modest number of them myself too. However, you're missing the point that the problem is not whether or not the URL is validated but whether it is safe to interpolate the URL into a command line as in OP's code.

Comment: Downvoting this because this is an insecure example and anyone doing this should be fired. The security implications of getting this wrong are massive, while easy secure alternatives exist.

Comment: @gomennathan Custom escaping is *not* reliable. `urllib.parse.urlparse` happily accepts `https://www.google.com"; reboot now"`, for example. For Unix `shlex.quote` works but there's a reason even that has a note pointing to `subprocess`.

Answer (score 20):

```
import urllib2
import time

max_attempts = 80
attempts = 0
sleeptime = 10 #in seconds, no reason to continuously try if network is down

#while true: #Possibly Dangerous
while attempts < max_attempts:
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com", timeout = 5)
        content = response.read()
        f = open( "local/index.html", 'w' )
        f.write( content )
        f.close()
        break
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        attempts += 1
        print type(e)
```

Comment: No `-c` equivalent here. Just downloads the file thrice.

Answer (score 15):

For **Windows** and **Python 3.x**, my two cents contribution about **renaming the file on download** :

1. Install [wget](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) module : `pip install wget`
2. Use wget :

```py
import wget
wget.download('Url', 'C:\\PathToMyDownloadFolder\\NewFileName.extension')
```

Truely working command line example :

```py
python -c "import wget; wget.download(""https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.17.2.tar.xz"", ""C:\\Users\\TestName.TestExtension"")"
```

*Note* : 'C:\\PathToMyDownloadFolder\\NewFileName.extension' is not mandatory. By default, the file is not renamed, and the download folder is your local path.

Comment: just my 2 cents. For users on windows with Anaconda, it looks like that there is no wget package. In this case, I would suggest using the requests lib that is more portable. Have a look at this [link](https://anaconda.org/search?q=wget). There are a few packages for win-64 but none from *official* sources.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the code adopted from the [torchvision library](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/dcfcc8675393749e852d8956b580b1660dfbea2d/torchvision/datasets/utils.py#L45):

```
import urllib

def download_url(url, root, filename=None):
    """Download a file from a url and place it in root.
    Args:
        url (str): URL to download file from
        root (str): Directory to place downloaded file in
        filename (str, optional): Name to save the file under. If None, use the basename of the URL
    """

    root = os.path.expanduser(root)
    if not filename:
        filename = os.path.basename(url)
    fpath = os.path.join(root, filename)

    os.makedirs(root, exist_ok=True)

    try:
        print('Downloading ' + url + ' to ' + fpath)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fpath)
    except (urllib.error.URLError, IOError) as e:
        if url[:5] == 'https':
            url = url.replace('https:', 'http:')
            print('Failed download. Trying https -> http instead.'
                    ' Downloading ' + url + ' to ' + fpath)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fpath)
```

If you are ok to take dependency on torchvision library then you also also simply do:

```
from torchvision.datasets.utils import download_url
download_url('http://something.com/file.zip', '~/my_folder`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me Improve a example with threads in case you want download many files.

```
import math
import random
import threading

import requests
from clint.textui import progress

# You must define a proxy list
# I suggests https://free-proxy-list.net/
proxies = {
    0: {'http': 'http://34.208.47.183:80'},
    1: {'http': 'http://40.69.191.149:3128'},
    2: {'http': 'http://104.154.205.214:1080'},
    3: {'http': 'http://52.11.190.64:3128'}
}


# you must define the list for files do you want download
videos = [
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2BHi.jpg",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/NURaP.jpg"
]

downloaderses = list()


def downloaders(video, selected_proxy):
    print("Downloading file named {} by proxy {}...".format(video, selected_proxy))
    r = requests.get(video, stream=True, proxies=selected_proxy)
    nombre_video = video.split("/")[3]
    with open(nombre_video, 'wb') as f:
        total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
        for chunk in progress.bar(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), expected_size=(total_length / 1024) + 1):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()


for video in videos:
    selected_proxy = proxies[math.floor(random.random() * len(proxies))]
    t = threading.Thread(target=downloaders, args=(video, selected_proxy))
    downloaderses.append(t)

for _downloaders in downloaderses:
    _downloaders.start()
```

Comment: This does none of the things OP asked for (and several things they didn't ask for).

Comment: The example try to show wget multi download feature

Comment: No one asked for that. OP asked for the equivalent of `-c`, `--read-timeout=5`, and `--tries=0` (with a single URL).

Comment: I understand, sorry :(

Comment: I'm really glad to see it here, serendipity being the cornerstone of the internet.  I might add whilst here though, that during my research I came across this for multithreading and the requests library:  requests-threaded
https://github.com/requests/requests-threads

Comment: correction - https://pypi.org/project/txrequests/  txrequests seems to be the best solution, albeit for a different problem to the one posed by this thread.

Answer (score 1):

easy as py:

```
class Downloder():
    def download_manager(self, url, destination='Files/DownloderApp/', try_number="10", time_out="60"):
        #threading.Thread(target=self._wget_dl, args=(url, destination, try_number, time_out, log_file)).start()
        if self._wget_dl(url, destination, try_number, time_out, log_file) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def _wget_dl(self,url, destination, try_number, time_out):
        import subprocess
        command=["wget", "-c", "-P", destination, "-t", try_number, "-T", time_out , url]
        try:
            download_state=subprocess.call(command)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        #if download_state==0 => successfull download
        return download_state
```

Comment: FYI: This won't work on Windows as the `wget` command isn't implemented there.

Answer (score -9):

TensorFlow makes life easier. **file path** gives us the location of downloaded file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv',
                                    fname='train.csv',
                                    untar=False, extract=False)
```

Comment: talk about an overkill