# facing issue with "wget" in python

Tags: python, wget

I am very novice to python. I am facing issue with "wget" as well as "  urllib.urlretrieve(str(myurl),tail)"

when I run script it's downloading files but filename are ending with "?"

my complete code :

```
import os
import wget
import urllib
import subprocess
with open('/var/log/na/na.access.log') as infile, open('/tmp/reddy_log.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    results = set()
    for line in infile:
        if ' 200 ' in line:
            tokens = line.split()
            results.add(tokens[6]) # 7th token
    for result in sorted(results):
        print >>outfile, result
with open ('/tmp/reddy_log.txt') as infile:
     results = set()
     for line in infile:
     head, tail = os.path.split(line)
                print tail
                myurl = "http://data.xyz.com" + str(line)
                print myurl
                wget.download(str(myurl))
                #  urllib.urlretrieve(str(myurl),tail)
```

output :

```
# python last.py
0011400026_recap.xml

http://data.na.com/feeds/mobile/android/v2.0/video/games/high/0011400026_recap.xml

latest_1.xml

http://data.na.com/feeds/mobile/iphone/article/league/news/latest_1.xml

currenttime.js
```

Listing the files :

```
# ls
0011400026_recap.xml?                   currenttime.js?  latest_1.xml?      today.xml?
```

Comment: Looks like a newline character since it's printing out an extra line every time. Hard to know for sure without seeing `line`

Comment: @CoryMadden what more information should i provide ?

Comment: `line` for starters.

Comment: myurl = 'http://data.na.com' + str(line)
        print myurl
#       wgproc = subprocess.Popen(['wget', '-r', '--tries=10', 'str(url)', '-o', 'log'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
#       (standardout, junk) = wgproc.communicate()
         wget.download(str(myurl))
        #urllib.urlretrieve(str(myurl),tail)

Comment: Please, not in the comments

Comment: @t.m.adam updated my complete code

Comment: instead of either, use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: No way the code thou show can give the output you show. Further, the indentation is wrong. Not to speak of posting code in comments. Also the temporary file is not needed. The match on `200` on the whole line sooner or later will lead to a false match. That said, my crystal ball tells me that `myurl = "http://data.xyz.com" + str(line.strip())` is indeed what you want.

Comment: tried myurl = "http://data.xyz.com" + str(line.strip())   ............ it downloaded with same issue ..... scoreboard.json?

Comment: @AshishKarpe It still sounds like an issue with your strings and we would have to see the actual string contents. I suggest you try `line[:-1]` to trim off a possible null character. I strongly suspect that `line` looks like `scoreboard.json<special character>` where "<special character>" is something that can't be converted to URL character.

Comment: @gboffi now wget is working is used strip() :   myurl = "http://data.ba.com" + str(line.strip())
        print myurl
        filename = wget.download(myurl)
        print filename

Comment: but now requests.post is not working :  post_url = "http://qa-web-net/nba" + str(line.strip())
        print post_url
        tail = str(tail.strip())
        myfiles = {'file': (tail, open(tail, 'rb'))}
        mypostfiles = str(myfiles.strip())
        print mypostfiles
        r = requests.post(myurl,files=mypostfiles)

Comment: error : # python reddy.py
latest_1.xml

http://data.ba.com/feeds/mobile/iphone/article/league/news/latest_1.xml
-1 / unknownlatest_1.xml
http://qa-web-.net/nba/feeds/mobile/iphone/article/league/news/latest_1.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reddy.py", line 37, in <module>
    mypostfiles = str(myfiles.strip())
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible explanation of the behaviour you experience is that you do
not sanitize your input `line`

> ```
> with open ('/tmp/reddy_log.txt') as infile:
>      ...
>      for line in infile:
>          ...
>          myurl = "http://data.xyz.com" + str(line)
>          wget.download(str(myurl))
> ```

When you iterate on a file object, (`for line in infile:`) the string
you get is terminated by a newline (`'\n'`) character — if you do not
remove the newline before using `line`, oh well, the newline character
is still there in what is produced by your use of `line` …

As an illustration of this concept, have a look at the transcript
of a test I've done

```
08:28 $ cat > a_file
a
b
c
08:29 $ cat > test.py
data = open('a_file')
for line in data:
    new_file = open(line, 'w')
    new_file.close() 
08:31 $ ls
a_file  test.py
08:31 $ python test.py
08:31 $ ls
a?  a_file  b?  c?  test.py
08:31 $ ls -b
a\n  a_file  b\n  c\n  test.py
08:31 $
```

As you can see, I read lines from a file and create some files using
`line` as the filename and guess what, the filenames as listed by `ls`
have a `?` at the end — but we can do better, as it's explained in the
fine manual page of `ls`

> ```
>   -b, --escape
>          print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters
> ```

and, as you can see in the output of `ls -b`, the filenames are not
terminated by a question mark (it's just a placeholder used by default
by the `ls` program) but are terminated by a newline character.

While I'm at it, I have to say that you should avoid to use a
temporary file to store the intermediate results of your computation.

A nice feature of Python is the presence of *generator expressions*,
if you want you can write your code as follows

```
import wget

# you matched on a '200' on the whole line, I assume that what
# you really want is to match a specific column, the 'error_column'
# that I symbolically load from an external resource
from my_constants import error_column, payload_column

# here it is a sequence of generator expressions, each one relying
# on the previous one

# 1. the lines in the file, stripped from the white space
#    on the right (the newline is considered white space)
#    === not strictly necessary, just convenient because
#    === below we want to test for non-empty lines
lines = (line.rstrip() for line in open('whatever.csv'))

# 2. the lines are converted to a list of 'tokens' 
all_tokens = (line.split() for line in lines if line)

# 3. for each 'tokens' in the 'all_tokens' generator expression, we
#    check for the code '200' and possibly generate a new target
targets = (tokens[payload_column] for tokens in all_tokens if tokens[error_column]=='200')

# eventually, use the 'targets' generator to proceed with the downloads
for target in targets: wget.download(target)
```

Don't be fooled by the amount of comments, w/o comments my code is just

```
import wget
from my_constants import error_column

lines = (line.rstrip() for line in open('whatever.csv'))
all_tokens = (line.split() for line in lines if line)
targets = (tokens[payload_column] for tokens in all_tokens if tokens[error_column]=='200')

for target in targets: wget.download(target)
```

Comment: now wget is working is used strip() :   myurl = "http://data.ba.com" + str(line.strip())
        print myurl
        filename = wget.download(myurl)
        print filename