# How to resume file download in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.6, python-3.5

I am using python 3.5 requests module to download a file using the following code, how to make this code "auto-resume" the download from partially downloaded file.

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

total_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length'))  

with open(file_path + file_name, "wb") as file:
    for data in tqdm(iterable = response.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024), total = total_size//1024, unit = 'KB'):
        file.write(data)
```

I would prefer to use only `requests` module to achieve this if possible.

Comment: I looked at it, but I could not understand.

Comment: It's feasible to resume the downloading using only `requests` if the server supports `Range` feature, however it's not that trivial if you want reliable download the file and check the integrity. If you found yourself writing to much low level downloading code, check this project https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think `requests` has this built in—but you can do it manually pretty easily (as long as the server supports it).

The key is [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) requests. To fetch part of a resource starting at byte 12345, you add this header:

```
Range: bytes=12345-
```

And then you can just append the results onto your file.

---

Ideally, you should verify that you get back a `206 Partial Content` instead of a `200`, and that the headers include the range you wanted:

```
Content-Range: bytes 12345-123456/123456
Content-Length: 111112
```

You also may want to pre-validate that the server handles ranges. You can do this by looking at the headers in your initial response, or by doing a `HEAD`, which checks for this:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

If the header is missing entirely, or has `none` as a value, or has a list of values that doesn't include `bytes`, the server doesn't support resuming.

And also maybe check the `Content-Length` to verify that you didn't already finish the whole file right before getting interrupted.

---

So, the code would look something like this:

```
def fetch_or_resume(url, filename):
    with open(filename, 'ab') as f:
        headers = {}
        pos = f.tell()
        if pos:
            headers['Range'] = f'bytes={pos}-'
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
        if pos:
            validate_as_you_want_(pos, response)
        total_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length'))  
        for data in tqdm(iterable = response.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024), total = total_size//1024, unit = 'KB'):
            f.write(data)
```

One common bug from people writing download manager type software is trying to keep track of how much has been read in previous requests. Don't do that's just use the file itself to tell you how much you have. After all, if you read 23456 bytes but only flushed 12345 to the file, that 12345 is where you want to start.

Comment: _One common bug from people writing download manager type software is trying to keep track of how much has been read in previous requests. Don't do that's just use the file itself to tell you how much you have._

this won't work if you're using multiple threads to download the file

Comment: @kurdishdevil if you are using multiple threads you would still want to start from what is on disk. so you would need to do both in that case