# wget set file name in batch download

Tags: python, bash, wget

I am trying to download files using an input file (`a.txt`) which has URLs using the following commands

```
wget -i a.txt
```

URLs are like

```
https://domian.com/abc?api=123&xyz=323&title=newFile12
https://domian.com/abc?api=1243&xyz=3223&title=newFile13
```

I want to set the name of the file from the URL by using the title tag (for example in the above URL name of the file download need to be `newFile12`) but can't find any way around it.

In order to get it done, I have to write a python script (similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313383/10549469) and run one by one is there any other way around.

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried so far and where you’ve gotten stuck.

Comment: I am not stuck but looking if someone knows a better way to do it without python script i.e., directly from `wget` command only. (I used the script from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313383/10549469)

Comment: there is no way to do this with only wget but I included a script that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script on the fly and and pipe it to bash. A bit slower than `wget -i` but would preserve file names:

```
 sed "s/\(.*title=\(.*\)\)/wget -O '\2' '\1'/" a.txt
```

When you are satisfied with the results, you can pipe it to bash:

```
sed "s/\(.*title=\(.*\)\)/wget -O '\2' '\1'/" a.txt | bash
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at `wget --content-disposition` or for loop with `wget -O <outputfile name> <url>`

Following command downloads the file with filename as provided by server (`vim-readonly-1.1.tar.gz`) instead of `download_script.php?src_id=27233`.

```
wget --content-disposition https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=27233
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the long URLs, I have the URLs from youtube video it still gets a bad name.

Comment: --content-disposition works if server supports it. Other option is you provide name with -O flag in wget command