# downloading video with python requests content receiving status

Tags: python, python-requests, download

I am downloading video using python requests module.
I want to know how much content is received currently while downloading like we see in browsers etc. x bytes downloaded of y bytes.

I have attached the code below what I'm using.
How can I achieve what I said above?

```py
print(f'[+] Downloading "{file}" ({sizeInMb} MB)...')
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    with open(filePath, 'wb+') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
        print(f'[-] Downloaded "{file}".')
        downloadCount += 1
```

Comment: I think you're expecting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28313383)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `iter_content()` method of the `requests` library to download the video as chunks and track the progress of the download. The `iter_content()` method returns a generator that yields the chunks of the file as they are downloaded. You can use the `len()` function to get the total size of the file, and then use a counter to track how many bytes have been downloaded so far.

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
import requests

def download_video(url):
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    file_size = int(response.headers['Content-Length'])
    downloaded = 0
    with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            downloaded += len(chunk)
            print(f'Downloaded {downloaded}/{file_size} bytes')
            f.write(chunk)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    download_video('https://www.example.com/video.mp4')
```

output be like:

```
Downloaded 0/1024000 bytes
Downloaded 1024000/1024000 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

To have a download bar, you can use the `wget` module in Python.

```
import wget

url = 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python3_tutorial.pdf'
file_name = wget.download(url)

print()
print(file_name)
```

I used a random PDF as a reference here. You can also update the downloaded file path and filename in the `wget.download` function, using the `out` argument.

Final Output:

```
100% [..........................................................................] 1015876 / 1015876
python3_tutorial.pdf
```