# Resume wget download in python

Tags: python, wget

In Linux we have a command `wget -c` with which we can continue or resume the download of the unfinished files. In `python`, by importing the `wget` library, I am not able to do the following feature. `Wget -c` also restricts the re-downloading of the preexisting file. Can anyone help me in finding a
`wget -c` equivalent in `wget` library of python.?

Comment: Have you tried using `os.system(wget -c)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how wedded you are to the wget library, or if you could use alternatives.

You could do the same with **urllib2**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963283/python-urllib2-resume-download-doesnt-work-when-network-reconnects) to a similar question about resuming a download when a problem arises.

Comment: I have done it on comand line and wget gets the job done on the command line and in python we have a library of wget so was exploring it and couldnt find the ans to my question.

Comment: OK - hopefully someone will propose a solution which works for you!

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP you can use Requests library. It's elegant and simple.
[This script](https://gist.github.com/tobiasraabe/58adee67de619ce621464c1a6511d7d9) can be halpfull to download files, resume downloads and validate downloads.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).